# Using PSModuleInfo::invoke(...) method

Tags: powershell

I am not able to pass arguments to a function that is defined in a module via invoke (PSModuleInfo::Invoke(...)). To be more specific, I need to pass a hashtable as a single argument.

The code sample below works meaning that the function in the module is being called. However, the argument is not passed.

In module:

```
function MyFunc($arg)
{
     ....
}
```

In Client:

```
$m =  Get-Module $name

$table = @{1 = 1; 2 = 2 }

$m.Invoke( {MyFunc}, @($table) ) # param is not passed
$m.Invoke( {MyFunc}, $table ) # param is not passed
$m.Invoke(  MyFunc,  $table ) # param is not passed

# Trying with scalar value
$x = 10
$m.Invoke( {MyFunc}, @($x) ) # param is not passed
$m.Invoke( {MyFunc}, $x ) # param is not passed
$m.Invoke(  MyFunc,  $x ) # param is not passed
$m.Invoke( {MyFunc}, 10 ) # This WORKS, 10 is assigned to $arg in a function
```

Based on my understanding, according to: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/system.management.automation.psmoduleinfo.invoke(v=vs.85).aspx, the first call to invoke should be the right syntax.

Comment: `$m.Invoke({param($param) MyFunc $param}, $x)`

Comment: Thank you PetSerAl! This works.